# Dart editor is it possible to use custom font?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Is it possible to add custom font to the dart editor, because I want to add and use [inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know witch version you are using but mine (0.5.20_r24275 on Windows) allows it.

Go to `Tools > Preferences`, then choose `Fonts` on the left side.

[image: Dart Editor Font Settings]

You can use any font that is installed on you system.